# c++ tuples, vector and threads code

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, vector, tuples

I have this code:

```
   void threaded_function(Model_factory &mf, ppa::Node *root)
{

  boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(result_mutex);
  typedef  vector<boost::tuple<ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, bool> >
  ::iterator traveling;

  if(!running_jobs.empty())
  {
      cout << "size of running " << running_jobs.size() << endl;
      boost::tuple<ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, bool> tuple_to_check = 
      running_jobs.front();
      running_jobs.pop();

      cout << "poping this object from running_jobs" << tuple_to_check << endl;
      cout << "new size of running " << running_jobs.size() << endl;

      lock.unlock();
      ppa::Node *tuplets_father = boost::get<0>(tuple_to_check);
      ppa::Node *first_son = boost::get<1>(tuple_to_check);
      ppa::Node *second_son = boost::get<2>(tuple_to_check);
      bool is_this_done = boost::get<3>(tuple_to_check);

      tuplets_father->start_alignment_new(&mf);

      lock.lock();
      cout << "size of the wait " << wait.size() << endl;

       boost::tuple<ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, bool> new_tuple
       = boost::make_tuple(tuplets_father, first_son, second_son, true);
       wait.push_back(new_tuple);
       cout << "pushing this object to waiting list" << new_tuple << endl;
```

Space to not have to scroll

```
       cout << "new size of the wait " << wait.size() << endl;  


     lock.unlock();

     lock.lock();

       for(traveling i = wait.begin(); i != wait.end(); i++)
      {
          if(boost::get<3>(*i) == true)
          {


              cout << "found in here pushing to running jobs " << *i <<  endl;
              boost::tuple<ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, bool>  tuple = *i;
              wait.erase(i);
              running_jobs.push(tuple);



          }
      }
       lock.unlock();

  } 

  else
  {

      boost::this_thread::yield();

  }
```

And this is a piece of my output:

```
 found in here pushing to running jobs (0 0x1dd00000142 0xffffffff00000143 1)    
 found in here pushing to running jobs (0 0 0 66)                                
found in here pushing to running jobs (0 0 0x1e000000142 67)                    
found in here pushing to running jobs (0 0x1e100000142 0xffffffff00000143 1)    
found in here pushing to running jobs (0 0 0 66)                                
found in here pushing to running jobs (0 0 0x1e400000142 67)                    
found in here pushing to running jobs (0 0x1e500000142 0xffffffff00000143 1)    
found in here pushing to running jobs (0 0 0 66)                                
found in here pushing to running jobs (0 0 0x1e800000142 67)                    
found in here pushing to running jobs (0 0x1e900000142 0xffffffff00000143 1)    
found in here pushing to running jobs (0 0 0 66)                                
found in here pushing to running jobs (0 0 0x1ec00000142 67)
```

It will go forever, and I wonder where is the mistake, is it with the logic? Most likely yes, but I could use some new pair of eyes, thanks.

Comment: You should probably try to reduce the size of your example to the smallest thing that exhibits the issue.

Comment: _`I wonder where is the mistake, is it with the logic`_ - us too. Perhaps it is supposed to run forever? Who knows

Comment: No it is not, it is supposed to end when there are no more waiting vector.

Comment: Hmmm ok I try the next time. @Michael Anderson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code invalidates `vector::iterator i` by calling

```
wait.erase(i);
```

It then increments the invalid `i` and uses it to determine if it should break out of the `for` loop.

You should instead use [`std::partition()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partition/).  That entire for-loop could be replaced with:

```
traveling running_jobs = 
                   std::partition( wait.begin(), wait.end(), is_not_running );

running_jobs.insert( running_jobs, wait.end() );

wait.erase( running_jobs, wait.end() );
```

`is_not_running` would be a function of your creation.  This would also reduce the complexity from O(n<sup>2</sup>) to O(n).

Comment: thanks, but why traveling::iterator? I didn't get that, and also what is is_not_running a bool or a func.

Comment: @user1423656: The link in my answer explains why `partition` returns an iterator, as well as what `is_not_running` would need to be.

Comment: Hi, this traveling::iterator is giving me, this: main.cpp:171: error: ‘iterator’ is not a member of ‘threaded_function(ppa::Model_factory&, ppa::Node*)::traveling’, any help?

Comment: ok I'm making progress here is another error error: ‘class threaded_function(ppa::Model_factory&, ppa::Node*)::traveling’ has no member named ‘insert, insert apparently do not exist in vec iterator

Comment: @user1423656 It sounds like you have a new question to ask.  Try to ask the question with the smallest code sample that exhibits your problem.  You'll probably get more help if you do that.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the partition solution, but if you just want to fix your code you should change your for loop to correctly increment i, which is:

```
for(traveling i = wait.begin(); i != wait.end();)
...
if (...)
{ 
    ...
    i = wait.erase(i);
    ...
}
else
{
     i++;
}
```

Comment: I though the erase deletes only the vector, why is messing with the iterator pointer? thanks (:

Comment: no. erase will remove the element and give you a valid iterator to the next element (or "end" if there is none). the iterator to the element removed is no longer valid.